# "We cant connect to file" as I open excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]When I open a particular excel workbook I am getting the message "We cannot connect to [http://www.stackoverflow.com/test/testfile.xls'](http://www.stackoverflow.com/test/testfile.xls%27). Please make sure you are using the connect web address".

I cannot find this file in File->Edit Links.
Where can I find this trouble file and turn it off? I hate seeing this popup each time I open the workbook.

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to "[Find external references in a workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-links-external-references-in-a-workbook-fcbf4576-3aab-4029-ba25-54313a532ff1?correlationid=7f86fc97-71c2-42d9-a572-5c57097dd80e&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#bmfind_external_references_used_in_cell)", and go to the Data tab > Existing Connections, check if there is any connection to this testfile.xls.

Comment: Tried both these, no more references of the file exist but still getting popup! I also deleted the reference in formulas-> name manager.  Could it be possible the url is from another file that is linked to my main file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a free add-in written by veteran Excel MVP Bill Manville to find links in formulas, data validation, named ranges, etc. Download from

https://manville.org.uk/software/findlink.htm

Comment: Thanks, do you got any other ways? My company wont let me download this add in.